# Bind Custom Property to Context

Tags: c#, wpf

I like to bind a custom property (owner Window) to my datacontext. How to do these in xaml.
I can not access on these property because my class is window and not MyView, its Window
 `<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView"`
By changing my xaml to MyView class i get some errors that my class needs a inheritance from window.

Codebehind:

```
DependencyProperty MyValueProperty, Property MyValue
```

Xaml:
***Bind MyValue to my datacontext.***

I want these
[image]

If i try to change the class name inside xaml:
[image]

I get these error
[image]

Comment: add code examples you tried and the error messages...

Comment: what is the exact error you got it ? Also share the sample you have tried.

Comment: By changing my xaml to MyView class i get some errors that my class needs a inheritance from window

Comment: Does MyView derive from `Window`? Or `Control` or `UserControl` or something else? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

you can instantiate a control that is
`<local:MyView xmlns:local="YourNameSpaceToMyView"` this way you can use your DP

Answer (score 0):

You can set your DataContext to the current instance of your window class like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.MyView" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}">
```

Then you can access the underlying properties easily.

To bind to your custom property, you can do something like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}, Path=MyProperty}"
```